# Как сделать поиск слов по всем html страницам?

Tags: javascript, html, строки, dom, search

Пишу сайт.

Подскажите с одним моментом.

Хочу написать поиск, но застопорился с получением всех html страниц.

Надо, чтобы поиск проходил по всем страницам и искал совпадения.

Как лучше это реализовать?

Помню, что есть функция FS - делать через неё?

Comment: например, у вас есть файн index.html  с JS кодом, который должен искать совпадения в других html файлах? Если другие файлы доступны по сети, то подгружайте странички по очереди и парсите.. если доступа к файлам из вне нету, то без серверного кода - никак)

Comment: Понял, попробую PHP добавить))

Comment: А данные страниц не находятся в БД? В принципе данные и оформление/шаблоны не должны пересекаться и если у Вас реализовано так-же, то почему не использовать поиск по БД? Загружать и парсить HTML это, извиняюсь, на извращение какое-то похоже.

Comment: Можно добавить виджет поиска от гугла еще например)

Comment: @XelaNimed Нет, не находятся. Это свёрстанный сайт, выкладываемый на битрикс. 
Я не знаком особо с БД. Вы рекомендуете весь контент закинуть в БД?
Порекомендуете, что почитать на БД?
P.S. Я фронт, который потихоньку изучает другие сферы, так что Ваша подсказка мне очень поможет

Comment: @Jour хочу именно свой поисковик) Стараюсь писать всё своими руками - это развивает в дальнейшей перспективе

Comment: @XelaNimed , если данные и шаблоны не должны пересекаться, то можно закидывать инфу в БД. А там через фетч будет легко найти

Comment: Если сайт открыт для индексации поисковыми системами, то как предложил Jour добавьте какой-либо виджет (от Google того-же). Если-же Вы задались целью написать своё, то в любом случае это БД, индексация, полнотекстовый поиск и много чего ещё.

Comment: @XelaNimed, спасибо большое. Видимо, мне в бек ещё рано. Надо укреплять фронт